# Grouping instances and summarizing by probability of a condition being true

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data with the following structure, where each responder is assigned a task that could either have a status being TRUE or FALSE.

```
  month         Responder       Status  Department
  2020-02-01    A                 TRUE  1
  2020-02-01    B                FALSE  1
  2020-02-01    B                 TRUE  1
  2020-02-01    C                 TRUE  1
  2020-02-01    C                 TRUE  1
  2020-03-01    D                FALSE  2
  2020-03-01    E                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    B                FALSE  1
  2020-03-01    F                FALSE  2
  2020-03-01    F                 TRUE  2
  2020-03-01    F                 TRUE  2
```

I want to output a data frame so that each responder is given a probability of having Status = FALSE.
I would like to group these results by month and department as follows:

```
  month         Responder    Prob_False    N    n
  2020-02-01    A            0             1    0
  2020-02-01    B            0.5           2    1  
  2020-02-01    C            0             2    0  
  2020-03-01    B            1             1    1
  2020-03-01    D            1             1    1
  2020-03-01    E            1             1    1
  2020-03-01    F            0.333         3    1
```

Where N is the total number of tasks assigned to the responder for that month and n is the number of tasks that had a FALSE status, grouped by the month and the responder.

I am trying to use the group_by and summarize functions in dplyr, but I guess I am not grasping the correct application for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by `mean` of the logical column, and get the frequency count with `n()` while getting the `sum` of logical vector for count of `FALSE`.  When we negate (`!`, the `TRUE/FALSE` changes to `FALSE/TRUE` and TRUE/FALSE would be stored as `1/0` thus the `mean` or `sum` works

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(month, Responder) %>% 
    summarise(Prob_False = mean(!Status), N = n(), n = sum(!Status))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   month [2]
#  month      Responder Prob_False     N     n
#  <chr>      <chr>          <dbl> <int> <int>
#1 2020-02-01 A              0         1     0
#2 2020-02-01 B              0.5       2     1
#3 2020-02-01 C              0         2     0
#4 2020-03-01 B              1         1     1
#5 2020-03-01 D              1         1     1
#6 2020-03-01 E              1         1     1
#7 2020-03-01 F              0.333     3     1
```

i.e. `mean(!Status)` is basicaly `sum(Status == FALSE)/n()`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(month = c("2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-01", 
"2020-03-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-03-01"), Responder = c("A", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "E", "B", "F", "F", "F"), Status = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE
), Department = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```